# Unable to use yo (yoeman-generator)

Tags: powershell, npm, npm-install, yo

I did a lot of googling but couldn't find the cause of the error.
I have tried setting the path variable.
Please tell some solution to this problem:

I installed `yo` using : `npm install -g yo`

I am working on PowerShell

[image]

Comment: The `yo` application is neither in path nor in `windows\system32` directory. Try using a full path to the executable.

Answer (score 0):

You can check whether the path variable for the `yo` application is set using:

```
$env:path -split ';'
```

If its not present there, you could either add it or use the full path to the application.

Comment: I haven't set any paths for 'yo' . My path enviromnet variable is : " C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_11\bin;C:\Users\SHIVAM\appData\Roamind\npm;C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin   "                                                                     Please specify what should i add to get it run

Comment: Im not sure but the application should be located in `C:\Users\SHIVAM\appData\Roamind\npm`.Check wheter you find `yo` there.